# When to use おなかすいた and when to use はらへった?

Tags: formality

From what I understand from listening to anime, both mean I'm hungry. But when do I use them properly? Is one more formal/polite than the other? Or is neither of them polite/formal enough?

In addition, how do I inform the other party that "I'm hungry let's go eat" politely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me, "お腹が空いた" sounds normal and polite as compared with "腹が減った," which sounds informal and sometimes vulgar, depending on the situation.

When you are taking a walk with your friend in downtown, say Asakusa, you may say "腹が減ったな。めしを食おう." But when you are taking a walk with your teacher or senpai, you may say "先生 (先輩)、お腹が空きましたね。何か食べて行きましょう."

We have a saying, "お里が知れる - One's birthplace is revealed," meaning "You can tell what class somebody belongs to from how he / she talks and behaves."

It'd be better not to say "腹へった" to others, unless they're your very close friends.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to only use 「腹が減った」 if you're speaking in all-male company, and to say 「お腹すいた」 (or it's polite ます form if needed) otherwise.

I remember the times when I said 「みんなさん腹減ってない？」 to a group of Japanese students, and they all laughed. It's apparently was a 失礼.

Comment: Also, they probably expected みなさん rather than みんなさん.

Comment: 「みなさんおなかすいてませんか」か「みんなはらへってない？」なら笑われなかったかも・・